# Reserve Flash memory space with XC32

Tags: c, mplab, xc32

I'm writing code for an `ATSAM` device using `MPLAB X` and `XC32` compiler. This device has 1Mbytes of flash memory and I need to put 200kBytes apart to be a placeholder for a configuration script (the main code will execute this script).

I'm trying to do this without messing with linker. This is what I'm doing:

```c
#pragma region name="plan_mem" origin=0xce000 size=0x32000

typedef struct {
    uint16_t version;
    //.... very long structure....
} Plan;

const Plan plan __attribute__((region("plan_mem"))) = {
    0x1, //....
};
```

While the code still works, I do have this warning from the compiler: `warning: 'region' attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]` and the final address is indeed ignored.

Why is it ignored since that came from the XC32 manual?

There is any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: Are you using GCC or the XC32 compiler? The question is tagged GCC and GCC is in the title but the body of the question says XC32...

Comment: Oops, my mistake here, thanks, going to fix it. I'm using XC32.

Comment: What about `-mreserve`in the linker script?